# Package tablefootnote Error: Package rotating loaded after tablefootnote

Tags: footnotes, rotating, sidewaystable

How can I solve this error appearing in the main file of my dissertation?

```
Package microtype Warning: Unable to apply patch 'footnote' on input line xx.
\begin{document}
```

Here is a view of the used packages

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[clean,pdf]{svg}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}%
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeglossaries
\usepackage{ltablex}% <-- added
\usepackage{siunitx}% <-- added
\usepackage{natbib}
\title{Bibliography management: \texttt{natbib} package}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{array,multirow,makecell}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{plate}{htpb}{plt}[chapter]
\floatname{plate}{Plate}
\usepackage{titlesec} 

\begin{document}
\part{Literature Review}
\input{./chapter1/chapter1}
\input{./chapter2/chapter2}
\input{./chapter3/chapter3}

\part{Contributions}
\input{./chapter4/chapter4}
\input{./chapter5/chapter5}
\input{./chapter6/chapter6}
\input{./Conclusion/Conclusion}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{references/references}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeXSE, I didn't face such an error message, what you mentioned. Can you update your setup and then try, also really you need this much of packages!

Comment: Also, please post your `MWE` upto `\end{document}`

Comment: That's not an error,  only a warning and also not what you show in the title of your question.

Comment: @UlrikeFischerI I think it's an error, not a warning. The document can not be compiled. The following message appears "NO PDF. This compile didn’t produce a PDF. "

Comment: @MadyYuvi I used this template to write my dissertation having these packages. I just added some. I'm still trying to figure out the MWE thing. As you recommended, I added to `\end{document}`.

Comment: For me it shows "Package tablefootnote Error: Package rotation loaded after tablefootnote" which directly leads to the solution...

Answer (score 1):

I solved it! Just moved `\usepackage{rotating}` before `\usepackage{tablefootnote}`.

Comment: Please accept this answer to mark the question as solved.

Comment: @CampanIgnis: They answered their own question and can only accept that answer after a while...